# Put thousands separator in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am sending via ViewData values to my view like this.

Controller

```
public List<string> ListarTarjetas()
{
    OpexDB db = new OpexDB();           

    List<string> Tarjetas = new List<string>();

    using (db)
    {
          var listTarjetasInformativas = db.SP_TARJETASINFORMATIVAS();
                
          foreach(var item in listTarjetasInformativas)
          {
               Tarjetas.Add(item.NOMBRE);
               Tarjetas.Add(item.MONTO.ToString());
          }
     }

     return Tarjetas;
}
```

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var DatosTarjetas = ListarTarjetas();

    ViewData["PrimerNombre"] = DatosTarjetas[0];
    ViewData["PrimerMonto"] = String.Format(DatosTarjetas[1], new CultureInfo("es-HN"));

    return View();
}
```

Part of my razor view:

```
<div class="inner">
   <p>@ViewData["PrimerNombre"]</p>           

   <p>@ViewData["PrimerMonto"]</p>

   <div class="icon">
      <i class="ion ion-pull-request"></i>
   </div>
</div>
```

Within my view, in the part of `<p>@ViewData["PrimerMonto"]</p>` this value 7218.19 is reflected, but I would like it to be reflected in this way, 7,218.19.

I have tried like this:

```
ViewData["PrimerMonto"] = String.Format(DatosTarjetas[1], new CultureInfo("es-HN"));
```

and other ways too. But I don't get any change.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format it just as a number or as currency, but if it's a string in your view data, you need to convert it to a number.
See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestNumberFormat()
        {
            string numberStringValue = "7891.12";
            double numberNumericValue = double.Parse(numberStringValue);

            string formattedValueWithSymbol = string.Format(new CultureInfo("es-HN"), "{0:c}", numberNumericValue);
            string formattedValue = string.Format("{0:N}", numberNumericValue);

            Console.WriteLine(formattedValueWithSymbol);
            Console.WriteLine(formattedValue);
        }
```

The output of this will be

```
Standard Output: 
L7,891.12
7,891.12
```